# How to get the nearest marker to a know point in the visible map area with Google Maps API v.3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers), but i have some regrets to apply in my situation becose i have many markers (atm ~5000, grown everyday).

In my application the user place his marker (lets call it marker A) clicking the map or via a geocode by address; I have to know if there is a marker in a specific radius of marker A.

As i said, i cant iterate throught all the markers, it will probably kill the user browser, and if possible i'll love to avoid ajax requests to search into my database.

Actually i insert the markers on the map via [MarkerManager](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.1/docs/reference.html)

Is there a way to search only between the markers in the map's visible area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many many research, i ended with the iteration solution ([demo here](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_array_sort.html)).

To decrease the number of items to iterate with, i divide in base of the state (at the moment is enaught), maybe in the future i can add further divisions.

If it can be usefull to someone else, my 'solution' implies an array like:

```
places = {
    "it":[
        "Rome",
        "Venice"
    ],
    "fr":[
        "Paris",
        "Lyon"
    ],
    "es":[
        "Madrid",
        "Barcelona",
        "Girona"
    ]
}
```

And a google geocode with the user marker coords to get the state ('fr', 'it') where to look for places.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method `getBounds()` which will retrieve `LatLngBounds` object. With this object, you can call the methods `getNorthEast(); getSouthWest()` methods which will retrieve the Northwest and Southeast bounds of your map respectively. 
Knowing these bounds, you can perform calculations in your application 
(pseudo code):

```
if (yourPointLatitude > southWestBoundLatitude && yourPointLatitude < northWestBoundLatitude && yourPointLongitude > northWestBoundLongitude && yourPointLongitude < southEastBoundLongitude)
{
    //take some action, the point is in the map bounds
}
```

Note: this case is only for specific geographic location -> it will only work for the northeast quarter of the world (for example Europe). If you want for different location, use other logic in the if statement and that's it...

Edit: look at these links for details:[Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)
[LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds)

Comment: Don't you mean if (yourPointLatitude > southWestBoundLatitude && yourPointLatitude < northEastBoundLatitude && yourPointLongitude > southWestBoundLongitude && yourPointLongitude < NorthEastBoundLongitude) ?