# How to search nearest google markers?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing a project where I need to find the closest 10 markers from my current location On Google map in Android.
Is there any API or inbuilt function/class that displays these things?
I have little bit knowledge of Google Maps in Android.

I need to find 10 closest marked place on google map and its lat long and title in my list view...

Plz Plz Help me out.!

Comment: see this [find nearest markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers) maybe helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use following method for finding distance between two geo points.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param lat1 Latitude of the First Location
 * @param lng1 Logitude of the First Location
 * @param lat2 Latitude of the Second Location
 * @param lng2 Longitude of the Second Location
 * @return distance between two lat-lon in float format
 */

public static float distFrom (float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2 ) 
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```

Here your first geo codes will be your current Position's geo code and other geo points are the geo points you want to compare with , you need to run a loop for it.

Comment: @ Android. Can you see my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563909/illegalstateexception-fragment-already-added-android?noredirect=1#comment84192332_48563909

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in function to retrieve nearby markers in the way you describe, but you should be able to build your own by calculating the distance to each marker and sorting the results.