# Finding all the markers inside a given radius

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps

Input: Given a specific co-ordinate (latitude and longitude) and radius
Output: Displaying all the markers which reside under that circle from given list of markers.

How can I do this in google maps?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just iterate all the markers you have and use the following function to get the distance from the specific co-ordinate to the marker: `computeDistanceBetween()`:

> To compute this distance, call computeDistanceBetween(), passing it two LatLng objects.

I found it over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en#Distance). Then just filter out all the markers that turn out to be close enough.

Comment: Will this consume google apis according to number of pointers since we need to call ComputeDistanceBetween() function in a loop? is this adding to payable cost?

Comment: @mahedhanu I would hope this is calculated client side, not subject to charges, but am not sure. Maybe worth experimenting.

Comment: you're right, but it's very expensive (computation-wise) if you have 10k markers.

Answer (score 9):

```
var targetLat=marker.getPosition().lat();
var targetLng=marker.getPosition().lng();

var targetLoc = new GLatLng(targetLat,targetLng);

var center= new GLatLng(centerLat, centerLng); 

var distanceInkm=center.distanceFrom(targetLoc) / 1000;

if(distanceInkm < radius){
// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: `GLatLng` is deprecated in V3, it's called `google.maps.LatLng` now

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example. Click map to draw a radius with selected radius and it would display all the markers from `all_locations` example array which fall inside the radius. Click on a marker to see the distance in meters from the radius center. (Click somewhere around New York's Second Street to see the example markers - map is already centered to that location)

```js
var map = null;
  var radius_circle = null;
  var markers_on_map = [];
  
  //all_locations is just a sample, you will probably load those from database
  var all_locations = [
   {type: "Restaurant", name: "Restaurant 1", lat: 40.723080, lng: -73.984340},
   {type: "School", name: "School 1", lat: 40.724705, lng: -73.986611},
   {type: "School", name: "School 2", lat: 40.724165, lng: -73.983883},
   {type: "Restaurant", name: "Restaurant 2", lat: 40.721819, lng: -73.991358},
   {type: "School", name: "School 3", lat: 40.732056, lng: -73.998683}
  ];

  //initialize map on document ready
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center on map startup
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', showCloseLocations);
  });
  
  function showCloseLocations(e) {
   var i;
   var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
   var address = $('#address').val();

   //remove all radii and markers from map before displaying new ones
   if (radius_circle) {
    radius_circle.setMap(null);
    radius_circle = null;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
    if (markers_on_map[i]) {
     markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
     markers_on_map[i] = null;
    }
   }
 
   var address_lat_lng = e.latLng;
   radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: address_lat_lng,
    radius: radius_km * 1000,
    clickable: false,
    map: map
   });
 if(radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());
   for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
    (function (location) {
     var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
     var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
     if (distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
      var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: marker_lat_lng,
       map: map,
       title: location.name
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function () {
       alert(location.name + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location");
      });
      markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
     }
    })(all_locations[j]);
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false&libraries=geometry"});
      </script>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
 
 <select id="radius_km">
  <option value=1>1km</option>
  <option value=2>2km</option>
  <option value=5>5km</option>
  <option value=30>30km</option>
 </select>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:500px; height:300px;">
</body>
```

Comment: @ChingChongPa it works for me in Firefox. It depends on browsers settings, etc,.. since it's loading http script from https page. Try it on your localhost, should work in any browser. If you get 'no API key' error, you can try to load the Google Maps JS api as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial instead of the `google.load("maps"..` way from the example.

Comment: is this example up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Load the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) and use [`computeDistanceBetween()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to find the distance of each marker from your centre point.

If the distance is within the radius, display the marker.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer given to this question: [Google Maps Api v3 - find nearest markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers)

You basically need to loop through your array of markers, and use a formula to calculate their distance from a given point (the center of the circle representing your search radius).

You can then exclude any markers which are further away than the radius, ad you will be left with a list of markers which are inside the circle.