# Can we get only hotels details near me using google place api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am new to google map and place API.I want to get the only information about hotel using google place API is it possible.

Comment: how ?can u please help me@SunilSingh

Comment: check these links - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_a_marker               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367594/google-maps-v2-android-get-a-list-of-markers                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295371/finding-all-the-markers-inside-a-given-radius

Comment: check this link also -https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup#api-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can start working with the Google Places API, you must add a Google API key to your app. Check [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) the steps on how to get a key for your app. Once you have an API key, you can add it to your app's manifest as described in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key).

Use Google Places API Web Service which allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories, such as hotels. You can search for places either by proximity or a text string. A [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) returns a list of places along with summary information about each place; additional information is available via a Place Details query. You can also create a [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_a_marker) for each hotel found and if the user clicks a hotel marker, it will show the details of that hotel in an [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows).

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) that allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given country. It then displays markers for all the hotels returned, with on-click details for each hotel.