# Distance between a searched address and nearest existing placemark on a google maps api v3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

I'm developing a web page with a Google Maps API v3. I currently have a functional map and search bar. I need to be able to display the distance from a searched address to the nearest placemark on one of the KML files on the map. How can I do this?

Here is the code for the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map; 
    var marker;
    var layers = [];
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (41, -73.4);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});


        layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80233620/South-and-North-County-Trailway.kml',
            {preserveViewport: true});
        layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/downloads/misc/cityracks.kml', 
            {preserveViewport: true});
        layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80233620/NWS%20Radar%20Images.kmz', 
            {preserveViewport: true});
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
                layers[i].setMap(map);
              }
        }

    function codeAddress () {
        var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)  {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
            map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
            marker.setPosition(results [0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(14);
            } 
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
        }); 
                            }
    function toggleLayer(i) {
      if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
      }
      else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);}
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the data in KML layers like that

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

> Because KML may include a large number of features, you may not access
>   feature data from the KmlLayer object directly. Instead, as features
>   are displayed, they are rendered to look like clickable Maps API
>   overlays.

Instead you can process the XML and add markers manually, then use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#spherical)  and `computeDistanceBetween()` to get the distance.  I usually multiply the distance by some number to account for turns (The distance formula gets a straight line distance). I believe around `1.2` was the most accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by processing the XML and adding markers manually?

Comment: you have to open the xml file with php and extract the points out and add the markers.  Google maps doesn't allow you to access that data via a kml layer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, how do I open the file with it?

Comment: Galen, I found another question related to this, and your answer to it seemed to work for other users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers/4060721#4060721. Can I use this same code in mine? if so, how do you display the calculated distance?

Comment: That wont work because you dont have markers on your map you have a kml layer.  Extracting the markers out of the kml layer is out of the scope of these comments.

Comment: do you recommend somewhere or someone that can help me extract the markers?

Comment: Look up how to parse xml with php