# GOOGLE MAPS API V3 - How to find the Nearest Marker of an array of markers (XML file)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

My name is Diogo, and i'm doing a web system using GOOGLE MAPS API V3, that find the nearest college, when the user submit his location using a input button (html).

I have a separated XML file that contains varyous Latitude and longitude data, and i need to compare the data of this array with the user location, to find the closest address in my xml file, and then draw closest the way from a point to another.

I don't know if i explained my question correctly, but here is the link to you see better what is my problem.
http://sistemapoliedro.com.br/teste/diogo/v3/

and the current JS map config file:
...sistemapoliedro.com.br/teste/diogo/v3/js/mapConfig.js

and the current XML map config file:
...sistemapoliedro.com.br/teste/diogo/v3/unidades-parceiras.xml

Obs: I have this project running on V2 version, but i am upgrading to V3 version. The "obsolete" link is here:
http://www.sistemapoliedro.com.br/sep/unidades_parceiras/

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_closestMarker.html)? (returns closest marker to a clicked point on the map, replace that with your geocoded result)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Api v3 - find nearest markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers)