# Find the closest marker to a new marker added Customer Service app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a fast food customer service application The call center should be able to add the address of the caller (a marker on the map) by clicking on the map that already has old markers (the branches) and automatically it should calculate the closest branch from the marker added.

I could add the markers into an array and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers) calculation function, nevertheless I need to know how to call this function after the clicking event and connect it to the new marker added.
The code is as follow

**Identifying the branches**

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var marker, i;
var locations = [
 ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546, 1],
 ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669, 2],
 ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443, 3],
 ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052, 4]];
```

**The Initialization function**

```
function initialize() {
   var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(3.171368, 101.653404);
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: haightAshbury,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      addMarker(event.latLng);
   });

   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
      })(marker, i));

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', find_closest_marker);

   }
}
```

**Adding new marker**

```
function addMarker(location) {
   var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
   });

   markers.push(marker); 
}
```

**Adding new marker to the array**

```
setAllMap(map) 
{
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
   {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
   }
}
```

**Calculating function**

```
function rad(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}
function find_closest_marker( event ) {
var lat = event.latLng.lat();
var lng = event.latLng.lng();
var R = 6371; // radius of earth in km
var distances = [];
var closest = -1;
    for( i=0;i<map.markers.length; i++ ) {
       var mlat = map.markers[i].position.lat();
       var mlng = map.markers[i].position.lng();
       var dLat  = rad(mlat - lat);
       var dLong = rad(mlng - lng);
       var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
       Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
       var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
       var d = R * c;
       distances[i] = d;
       if ( closest == -1 || d < distances[closest] ) {
          closest = i;
       }
    }

alert(map.markers[closest].title);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Google Maps Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to calculate distances. Both parameters must be LatLng objects.

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerPosition, mainPosition);
```

Ofcourse you need to load geometry library

```
&libraries=geometry
```

Working example of your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReneKorss/6DCTp/25/). Closest marker will be printed in console (F12). Note the comments in code, all mistakes fixed.

Comment: whats the use of this line ?`$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();`

Comment: The example is working perfect on the link you gave me, but when I copy the code in my localhost project the map does not show up are not I supposed to just add the library like this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>`

Comment: You must call `initialize();` on page load. Thats what `$(document).ready(function () {initialize();});` does with jQuery. You can also call it simply in script tag. I updated example not to use jQuery. And yes, you have to add library like that.

Comment: Thank you so much, best support ever seen since I joined

Answer (score 0):

Before adding new marker to map and pushing to the array, you need to pass latitude and longitude values of that point to the function `find_closest_marker()`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   find_closest_marker( event );
   addMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

will alert closest marker's title.

However, your code has a few mistakes:

1. Your marker array is just `markers`, but in `find_closest_marker`, it is `map.markers[]` so you must change them to `markers[]`.
2. In `addMarker()`, you are defining your marker with name `marker1` but pushing to array as `marker`.
3. Not a mistake but forgotten one, when you are creating markers from your `locations[]` array in for loop, you need also push them into your `markers[]` array: `markers.push(marker);` at the bottom of `for` loop.

Comment: Should I put both the `markers[]`  and `locations[]` in one array?

Comment: No you won't put `locations`, but when you are creating markers from `locations` array in for loop, you need also put them into array `markers`.

Comment: Followed all your steps exactly like they are, and it alerts "undefined" right now, I also have the following warning when inspect the page "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." , where do you think the problem could be?

Comment: I have found that your markers don't have titles and we are trying to show titles. Try displaying latitude-longitude values in alert: `alert(markers[closest].getPosition().lat());` for latitude

Comment: Also look at infowindow, you are not creating them as new infowindows.