# How to auto calculate and display the nearest distance of airport using googlemap?using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display nearest distance of airport using googlemap.

i have lattitude and longitude of address.

i got all nearest airport code but want to display nearest distance...

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers

Comment: if you have both latitde and longitude please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
    var a = 
        Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
        ; 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

call your function `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)` then check which is the lowest.

Reffered from [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)