# Adding same google map search to my site

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a google map with a few markers already on it. When a user clicks a  *Get Directions* button, I'd like a search box with the same functionality as the Google Map's. When users type an address/postcode in it, they get a "directions" button and if clicked on it will calculate and draw the distance between the address you typed in and the closest marker to it. I've had a very good look at the API, especially this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places but I couldn't find anything that matches exactly the google search box and its functionalities. Does anybody know if the above is doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Places Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) as far as implementing something similar to Google Maps. However, from what you've said, rather than Places, you can probably get away with just an input box, unless you actually need Places data. If all you need is to get directions, you'll want to incorporate the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). With the input box as the origin and the [nearest marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers) as the destination, you can then calculate directions.

Comment: cool thanks, although they wanted a precise copy of the search box in google map rather than a generic input box. Anyway, after reviewing competing website, it has been decided to launch instead a google maps with parameters stored in the URL, so I'll go for that approach