# Google map locations sorted by nearest first on map

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map API. I have 4 destinations and I want to get their locations ordered by nearest location first followed by second nearest. I have to show on Google Map which location is 1st being the nearest and then the next nearest and so on. So far I have only successfully calculated the distance between 2 locations by using below code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getDistance("DECATUR FARM ROAD CHICHESTER PO20 8JT", "UNIT 01 CLIFF REACH GREENHITHE DA9 9SW");
    }

    public int getDistance(string origin, string destination)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int distance = 0;
        //string from = origin.Text;
        //string to = destination.Text;
        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false";
        string requesturl = url;
        //string requesturl = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + from + "&alternatives=false&units=imperial&destination=" + to + "&sensor=false";
        string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
        try
        {
            distance = (int)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value");
            return distance;
        }
        catch
        {
            return distance;
        }
        return distance;
        //ResultingDistance.Text = distance;
    }

    protected string fileGetContents(string fileName)
    {
        string sContents = string.Empty;
        string me = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
                sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { sContents = "unable to connect to server "; }
        return sContents;
    }
```

How do I show the destinations according to their distance on google map. Any tip or pointers will be appreciated.

Please see the image, this is what I am trying to accomplish
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057665/google-maps-api-v3-find-nearest-markers

Answer (score 0):

Happy :)  Enjoy Coding..

```
 ArrayList arraylist;
        List<string> adddistance = new List<string>();
        List<string> getfinallist = new List<string>();
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "UNIT 01 CLIFF REACH GREENHITHE DA9 9SW,PINETOP BIRKLANDS LANE ST ALBANS AL1 1EE,HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BT,OLD RECTORY HOLYWELL HILL ST ALBANS AL1 1BY";
        button("DECATUR FARM ROAD CHICHESTER PO20 8JT", s);
    }

    public void button(string orign , string destination)
    {

        string[] words = destination.Split(',');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            getDistance(orign, word);
        }
        sorting();


    }

    public int getDistance(string origin, string destination)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int distance = 0;



        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin +  "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false";
        string requesturl = url;

        string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);


      string  strdistance = (string)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value") + " , " + destination + " , ";
            adddistance.Add(strdistance);




        return distance;


    }


    public void sorting()
    {  
       adddistance.Sort();

        string getfirststring = adddistance.FirstOrDefault().ToString() ;
        var vals = getfirststring.Split(',')[1];

        getfinallist.Add(getfirststring.Split(',')[1]);

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       adddistance.RemoveAt(0);

       foreach (string cat in adddistance) // Loop through all strings
       {
           builder.Append(cat); // Append string to StringBuilder

       }


       adddistance.Where((wors, index) => index % 2 == 0);
       string result = builder.ToString();

       string[] words = result.Split(',');
       string[] even = words.Where((str, ix) => ix % 2 == 1).ToArray();

       adddistance.Clear();

       foreach (string word in even)
        {                //string get = Regex.Match(word, @"^[" + numSet + @"]+$").ToString();

            if (word != " ")
            {
                getDistance(vals, word);
            }               


        }
        sorting();


    }
    protected string fileGetContents(string fileName)
    {
        string sContents = string.Empty;
        string me = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
                sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { sContents = "unable to connect to server "; }
        return sContents;
    }
```